# Java XML Transformer Only Outputs XML Header

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm working on a bit of a project for my own amusement that involves outputting the contents of several variables to an XML file. However, when I put the program, the transformer only outputs the first line (the XML header) and nothing else. The saveData() method is called before writeFile(), and I've outputted the value of the variables to the console before calling writeFile() so I know they have a value.

Code below:

```
public class Output {   
    private static double citySizeMiles;
    private static double citySizeAcres;
    private CityType type;
    private static int gpLimit;
    private static long totalWealth;
    private static long cityPopulation;

    public static void saveData() {
        cityPopulation = CityGenerator.cityPop;
        citySizeMiles = City.getCitySizeMiles(cityPopulation);
        citySizeAcres = City.getCitySizeAcres(cityPopulation);
        gpLimit = City.getGoldLimit();
        totalWealth = CityGenerator.cityWealth;
    }

    public static void writefile() {
        try {           
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            // Root Elements
            Document doc = builder.newDocument();
            Element root = doc.createElement("data");

            // Data Element
            Element data = doc.createElement("City");
            root.appendChild(data);

            Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("name");
            attr.setValue("Test");
            data.setAttributeNode(attr);

            // City size (sq miles)
            Element sizeMi = doc.createElement("sizeMiles");
            sizeMi.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(citySizeMiles)));
            data.appendChild(sizeMi);

            // City size (acres)
            Element sizeAc = doc.createElement("sizeAcres");
            sizeAc.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(citySizeAcres)));
            data.appendChild(sizeAc);

            // Population
            Element pop = doc.createElement("population");
            pop.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(cityPopulation)));
            data.appendChild(pop);

            // GP limit
            Element gpLim = doc.createElement("gpLimit");
            gpLim.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(gpLimit)));
            data.appendChild(gpLim);

            // Total fluid wealth
            Element wealth = doc.createElement("totalWealth");
            wealth.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(totalWealth)));
            data.appendChild(wealth);

            // Write to XML file
            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            tf.setAttribute("indent-number", 4);

            Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
            trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");

            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            //StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("D:\\test.xml"));

            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

            trans.transform(source, result);

        } catch(ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch(TransformerException tfe) {
            tfe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert on DOM (I avoid it like the plague, and encourage everyone else to do likewise) but I think you have failed to connect the root element to the document node.

Comment: I too am new at DOM (and was unaware of an alternative). Do you have any suggestions regarding this alternative, like a link to more information, or an explanation on how I failed to connect the root element to this document node?

Comment: My preferred tree models are JDOM and XOM. They are much simpler than DOM, much more Java-oriented, and designed with a much better understanding of XML (DOM started out as an HTML thing, and namespaces were an afterthought). But my real preference is not to process XML in Java at all: XSLT and XQuery do the job much better. As to the specifics, in the same way as you have done root.apppendChild(data), you need to connect the root element to the document node.

Comment: Such a simple fix! Oh well, I prefer fixes that only take one line of code and not hours of pulling stuff apart. Thank you very much, sir!